# pip не использует .pypirc

Tags: python, pip

Как сказать `pip`, чтобы он использовал конфиг `.pypirc`? Не могу указать путь к приватному репозиторию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, `pip`, в отличие от `twine` и `setup.py`, не умеет работать с `.pypirc`. Это большая проблема для всего сообщества. Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, обычно используют:

```
pip install -r requirements.private --extra-index-url https://your-url.your-domain
```

Но это не решает вопрос множественных конфигов. Ещё одно решение -- это использовать другой менеджер зависимостей. Здесь вы можете найти некоторые из них:

- pipenv (более совершенная штука, нежели *pip*)
- poetry (единственный файл с конфигурацией, относительно прост в использовании)
- https://flit.readthedocs.io
- dephell (объединяет в себе монго менеджеров пакетов, в том числе *pip*, *pipenv*, *poetry*, *flit*, но он довольно сложен по сравнению с *poetry*)

Answer (score 0):

> pip не использует .pypirc

А он и не должен. `.pypirc` - это файл конфигурации для *закачивания* пакетов на PyPI, а не для установки пакетов оттуда. Утилиты, которые созданы для паблишинга пакетов, например `twine`, читают `.pypirc`; `pip` - пакетный менеджер, он пакеты в PyPI не загружает. Так что все правильно.

Comment: Правильно или нет -- это отдельный вопрос. Это контринтуитивно. Огромное количество файликов, которые задают конфигурацию. Кроме того, об этом не написано в одном месте и прежде чем разберёшься, пройдёт очень много времени. Кажется, что это должно быть в одном месте

Comment: По такой логике можно сказать, что `pip` и `/etc/hosts` не использует, это большая проблема для всего сообщества! А ответ прост - `.pypirc` имеет столько же отношения к `pip`, сколько и `/etc/hosts`.